# Catch Windows Installer error messages with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

Is there a possibility to catch error messages produced by Windows Installer with PowerShell? In my scenario I want to invoke a msi file and in case of ots failure I need to catch a specific error message to invoke other actions.

I tried the following code but the error message could not be caught:

```
$item = "pathtomsi.msi"

try{

    $ErrorActionPreference = "stop"    
    Invoke-Item $item | Out-Null

} catch {

    Write-Host "Error while trying to install software: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```

I found this [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835(v=vs.85).aspx) on the internet: Could this error values maybe help? But how could them be caught by PowerShell during an installation of an msi file?

Comment: In the case of an error, the windows installer engine msiexec  would return  an error code. You will have to basically check for the exit code from the msiexec process. I am not aware of how to do that in Powershell . However, this is is the general methodology followed.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont know how to catch the exit code of msiexec in the powershell script.